# BMI Calculator bug?! Java

Tags: java, math

Ok, so  I wrote this simple code to calculate the BMI and provide the result according to the values entered (ie: BMI + normal/obese etc). I randomly started testing it and found out it worked for all the values that I put in EXCEPT for weight = 73 and height = 1.71...

```
   package basics;

   import java.util.*;

   public class BMI {

   public static void main(String[] args)

 {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double W, H, BMI;

    System.out.print("Enter weight in kg");
    W = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter height in m: ");
    H = sc.nextDouble();

    BMI = W/(H*H);
    System.out.println("Your BMI is : " + (int) BMI);

 if (BMI < 18.5)
        System.out.println("Underweight");

 if (BMI >= 18.5 && BMI <= 24.9)
        System.out.println("Normal");

 if (BMI >=25 && BMI <= 29.9)
        System.out.println("Overweight");

 else
     if (BMI >= 30)
        System.out.println("Obese");

}

    }
```

I think it may be because the BMI calculated for these values is 24.9 which is a borderline value. Could someone please help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is, but I want to tell you the following,
In this following expression `(BMI >=25 && BMI <= 29.9)` you can change the last operator to `<` instead of `<=` and the last number to `30`, so it will also include values like `29.95`. Like this: `(BMI >=25 && BMI < 30)` (It's the same thing with all the other IF statements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What would your code display if the BMI was 24.95? It's not normal as it's not less than or equal to 24.9, and not overweight as it's not greater than or equal to 25.

Rewrite the if statements like so:

```
if (BMI < 18.5)
    System.out.println("Underweight");

if (BMI >= 18.5 && BMI < 25)
    System.out.println("Normal");

if (BMI >=25 && BMI <= 30)
    System.out.println("Overweight");

else
    if (BMI > 30)
        System.out.println("Obese");
```

or even as

```
if(BMI < 18.5) System.out.println("Underweight");
else if (BMI < 25) System.out.println("Normal");
else if (BMI < 30) System.out.println("Overweight");
else System.out.println("Obese");
```

I would prefer the latter as it minimizes the number of superfluous comparisons, using an if...else if... else if...else structure instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're right.

```
73 / (1.71 * 1.71) = 24.964...
```

this is *neither below 24.9 nor above 25*. Java makes no assumptions that you want only 1 decimal-place. In general, to capture the idea of "up to and including", you should use a pair of `<` and `>=`.